# SSIS flat file source error failed to execute

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a text file that I want to import to my database.
I have an error so every 2 rows of the text file represents one row divided to 2 columns. What to put on both column and row delimiter to get what I want?

The output = every 2 rows represents only 1 row with 2 columns. This is the input:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a simple of the data and the expected output.

Comment: I'm not aware of any driver that lets you choose every second carriage return as a row delimiter. I suggest you import it as is and use a SQL script to stock the rows together. Also, it's much nicer if you copy/paste the data sample into your question.